# Spring boot data jar with embedded database

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to write a Java spring application with rest api that should persist states data etc

When I package the jar the user I send it to should be able to install it without any additional software for databases so what is the best way to do this?

I tried h2 in memory dB but when server is restarting the database is gone I tried mongo but I need the mongo client /server app so how can I ship a database with my app?

Comment: Use H2 with a file store!

Comment: can i use mongodb embedded with a file store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about http://hsqldb.org/ ?
It just saves data in a file format, easy setup